# Is there anywhere that has not been at war with Britain?

Tags: british-empire, britain

Is there anywhere that has not been at war with Britain?

"Anywhere" would mean "a contemporary country that was part of an empire or state that was at war with the United Kingdom or one of the earlier constituent countries of the British Isles". For "was part of an empire or state" we can say "was claimed by and/or under the control of an empire or state at war with Britain, and someone from there could have conceivably met the British in battle other than as a simple mercenary." Add: Private adventurers and mercenaries should be excluded.

So all of South America counts, as Britain was at war with the Spanish Empire several times. Switzerland counts, as it fought at some times on the French side in the Napoleonic wars. China counts (opium wars). Norway counts, several medieval wars with England and Scotland. Turkmenistan and Kyrgyzstan count, as there was an Anglo-Indian army fighting there in 1918-9.

Perhaps Mongolia? Anywhere else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46693/discussion-on-question-by-user24000-is-there-anywhere-that-has-not-been-at-war-w).

Comment: This is amazing. I am told I must edit the question to get it considered. I can't appeal to any authority, as I don't have the privileges. I edit the question. My edits get deleted. Nobody explains anything. What kind of place is this?

Comment: It's on topic, it clearly a history question.

It's clear what I'm asking. There is no ambiguity here. I want suggestions as to candidates for regions (defined for convenience as the territory of a modern country) with which any nation residing in the island of Britain has not been in a state of war.

Nor is it opinion-based. Either a country was or was not at war with another. This is certainly not a question of opinion, compared with most questions on the site.

Comment: Neither is it too broad under the definition on the help page. This does not require a book, nor does it have multiple competing answers. It asks for a list of a few countries. Neither do the answers need to be long by the standards of most on the site. The question, even as originally posed, is capable of a more concise answer than most on the site.

Comment: Sheesh. Lighten up guys. I'm British. This came out of a light-hearted discussion that we were having at work. History is history, and in the past. You don't have to take personal responsibility for it.

I defined "anywhere" as the territory of a modern country, just to prevent excessive nit-picking. The choice is perhaps a little arbitrary, but the question needed some kind of limit.

Comment: Perhaps the question could also be asked of other countries, quite fairly. We chose Britain because we are British. It is not "too broad", as for example, Sweden has never been at war with Greece, Turkey, or Persia/Iran, as far as I know.

The question, as asked, is clear, factual, specific, and would benefit from the input of historians and history buffs. Therefore, it meets the requirements as specified in the help page.

Comment: I would definitely appreciate more objective, factual input. There is no need for either rancour or apologies.

Comment: Some people brought up other reasons for disliking it, which are not valid reasons for closure according to the help page, so cannot be used as an excuse to close this question. However, I will address them anyway, but it must remain very clear that whatever your determination on these points, none are not a valid reason for closure.

"Why pick on Britain?" - well, with my fellow native Britons, at work, one lunchtime, we were discussing this question about our own country's history. Perhaps if we were Mongolian, we would have asked the question about Mongolia, or Vietnamese, about Vietnam.

Comment: "Are there any countries that have not been at war with all other countries at one time or another?" No. Neither has Britain. This point would be totally irrelevant, even if it were true, which it isn't. If I cared, I could even find the question offensive in its implications.

"Given your broad definition of what is a country now vs what was a belligerent then, the answer is almost certainly going to be no." If it that were the case, then it would be the answer. However, it isn't, neither for Britain, nor as far as I know, for any other country.

Comment: "... ridiculous broad scope which basically renders the question meaningless" -  This is actually a rather meaningless accusation all in itself. There is no requirement in the specification for any question to have a specific "meaning". This sounds very much like special pleading. It frankly sounds that, far from finding the question "meaningless", some individuals invested it with a specific "meaning" that it never had.

Comment: I also note that those who voted to close it, then continued to propose specific answers, so obviously the question was neither too broad, nor too meaningless, for them to address.

It feels now that closing the question is not so much a question of censorship, but outright cyberbullying. I would respectfully ask people to vote to reopen the question, at least so as preserve the reputation of the site, if for not other reason.

Answer (score 1):

## Nope!

There is nowhere that the British did not touch with war.  As a last ditch attempt, I thought perhaps Antarctica would have been spared - as there are no people to fight! But no, the Nazis were there too, and the British bombed them.

Greenland? Nope, part of Denmark. Madagascar? Nope, WWII Campaign. Islands in the Pacific? Nope, colonies everywhere. Central Asia? Nope, part of Russia. Africa? Nope, all colonized by various European powers. I though maybe because Ethiopia wasn't initially colonized, but Nope, that was part of Italy, which the British fought during WWII.

That just leaves the moon and other extra-terrestrial areas.

Comment: Actually, being colonised by a European power that Britain did not later go to war with would be a way for a territory to be discounted. I mentioned Congo, Mali, Burkina Faso - unless you know otherwise, of course.

Comment: @user24000 [British in Mali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Serval)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that British troops didn't go north from Ghana, and that British never had an incursion into Congo, but I don't have anything yet.

Comment: Need to look into the Marshal Islands as well a Chad

Comment: re: Mali. Very good. Very interesting. Not sure that counts, as it was a military action in alliance with the government of the time. And the rebellion was not an alternative government that had de facto control over the country, but a local rebellion loosely allied with other foreign forces.  Borderline, but technically not "at war with Mali", although certainly "at war in Mali".

Comment: I can't find anything on Chad either. Was it claimed by the Turkish Empire during the Greek War of Independence?

Comment: 1916, the British attacked Tanganyika from the Belgian Congo, but in alliance with the Belgian government, so again technically not at war with the Congo.

Comment: Maybe Chad and Burkina Faso were under Moorish Rule during the Crusades?

Comment: Seems that Burkina Faso and Mali weren't yet Muslim during the Crusades. Burkina Faso and Chad were independent up to colonial times, and Mali was at least partly Moroccan, which was independent of Turkey, and usually allied to England and, later, Britain.

Comment: it seems that the British went north from the coast when the French moved in to central West Africa. The borders are as far as they got during the "Scramble for Africa". Of course, the showdown was in the east at Fashoda.

Comment: I thought of perhaps Malta. The UK took it from the French. The islanders never resisted, and public uprisings during the British occupation were directed at the Italian elite, and not the British themselves. It gained its independence peacefully. However, it was part of the Roman Empire, and therefore the Iceni and Catevellauni etc. might have fought them. Although those political entities do not make up the current UK, they are definitely in the British Isles, and so I think we have to count them.

Comment: Better would be Mali or Burkina Faso. I don't know West African history so well, but as far as I know the British presence was confined to the coast. Congo (DRC) might be another - although Stanley fought his way across it, he was merely a private adventurer, not a state agent.

Comment: When was New Zealand at war against Britain?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Here is one, you'll have to look the rest up yourself: [Invasion of the Waikato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Waikato). Believe it or not, New Zealand was not historically part of England. The British took it over in something called *colonialism*.

Comment: @axsvl77: But from what I've read, 23 years *before* that, several Maori chiefs asked the King of England for protection from a French takeover and for the imposition of law on British settlers. After a negotiation, 500 Maori chiefs signed the treaty of Waitangi giving the Maori the same rights as British subjects, enshrining the chiefs land rights and giving the British monarch rule over New Zealand. That makes the subsequent Waikato invasion seem unlike a war between *New Zealand* specifically and Britain (or any "constituent country" thereof).

Comment: So legally speaking, was it a protectorate or a crown colony or what during the invasion of the Waikato?

Comment: @axsvl77: After 1840, New Zealand was something I expect the OP would regard as what the OP calls "a contemporary country", albeit fledgling. Though it isn't without controversy, most NZ sources regard the 1840 treaty as New Zealand's founding document.